# Shibboleth: SAML Assertion Attributes with different datatypes

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth, idp

Returned SAML assertion for all the attributes default to

> xsi:type="xsd:string"

In Assertion response, it showing like below

```
<saml2:Attribute 
            FriendlyName="givenName" 
            Name="givenName" 
            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
            <saml2:AttributeValue 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:type="xsd:string">testshibboleth
            </saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
```

Now, I want to change **xsi:type** from **string** to **Boolean or Integer or Duration** like different data types.

Is there any possibility to do that?

I followed a few articles and they are telling to update metadata

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/MetadataDrivenConfiguration

I tried updating metadata to accept boolean at least but not able to return those in assertion and not sure how to use that at attribute-filter.